# How to map keyboard shortcut "select all" (CTRL+A) to "seleccionar todo" (CTRL+E) in windows application?

Tags: visual-c++

My desktop application is using shortcut (CTRL+A) to select all text from current focused window. My application runs in different localization including spanish language. But in spanish language it is not selecting all text by using (CTRL+A). (CTRL+A) in spanish is "open". "CTRL+E" is used to select all text from spanish (notepad). Can anyone tell me how to map these two shortcuts in windows desktop application? (os: windows xp, windows 7 (32 & 64) bits)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you write this application?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple accelerator table resources, one for each locale.  The resource editor should let you assign each accelerator table to a particular locale.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically mentions localization as a benefit of accelerator tables.